# Possibility of a pointer memory leak?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, memory-leaks

I have a basic Game class written in c++, and a Character class which takes a pointer to the game as an argument for its constructor.  I am fairly new to all of this newfangled "C++" and "pointer" jazz, so please bear with me if this seems like a noobish question.  The actual code has much more to it, but for demonstration purposes I have compressed it down a bit:

```
class Game {
  Game() { /* blah blah blah */ };
  ~Game() {};
};
class Character {
  Character(Game *game, unsigned int x, unsigned int y) {
    /* here there be dragons */
  };
  ~Character() {} // empty destructor
};
```

My question is, do I need to delete the pointer to the main Game instance after I'm done with any given Character, or is the pointer completely unaffiliated with memory leaks? I have 800+ characters in one game at any given point in time, so if the pointer were to cause a memory leak there would be a bit of an issue.

Comment: Does a `Character` *own* the `Game` object?

Comment: Is the last instance of `Character` responsible for deleting `Game`? If so, you may have a design issue. But the solution in that case would be `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Hint: [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

Comment: There's no way of knowing from the code you posted.

Comment: Who owns the `Game` instance? Does each character own a separate one? Use `unique_ptr`. Do all characters collectively own a single one? Use `shared_ptr`. Does something else own the game and pass a pointer to characters? Use a `weak_ptr` or raw/`observer_ptr`, whichever makes the most sense for the situation.

Comment: No, the game instance is deleted when it falls out of scope.  I'll look into smart/shared pointers too, I've seen those here and there around the internet.  Characters don't own the game object; rather, they just need access to it and its members and I preferred to stay away from references...

Comment: Don't bother with smart pointers unless you need to manage the lifetime of dynamically allocated objects.

Comment: The game instance is (unfortunately) a global object, and it holds all of the characters within itself.  Those characters, on the other hand, need access to the methods and properties of the game they're stored in, such that if one character alters a game property it is altered for all of the other characters under that game as well.

Comment: Re, "...if the pointer were to cause a memory leak..." Pointers don't cause memory leaks.  Memory leaks happen when your program continually allocates new objects (e.g., by calling `new Foo` ) and fails to `delete` at least some objects that it no longer needs.

Comment: @0xDEADBEEF that’s a bad advice. Raw pointers are good. I want a vector iterator to be a raw pointer, not a smart pointer. **Owning** raw pointer are bad. Game characters most likely don’t own the game.

Comment: Certainly it is. It’s C++, not Java. You don’t want to pay the costs of creating a shared_ptr every time you need to access the pointer when you are writing a game loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, do I need to delete the pointer to the main Game instance after I'm done with any given Character

Not necessarily.

The pointed `Game` instance should be destroyed as should all objects sure, but should a `Character` instance be responsible for that?

You say that there will be many character instances. Consider: Will there be many game instances as well? Do each character point to their own game object?

---

If each character has their own separate game then it indeed does make sense for the character to be responsible for the destruction of their game. In that case, it might make li ttle sense to use pointers, as it would be simpler to use a direct subobject.

But if many characters refer to a shared game (which I suspect is the case), then a single character can't have sole ownership of that game, because as soon as any one character is destroyed, the others would still be pointing to that game.

---

Here are two approaches to shared ownership

1. Use a game instance that has longer lifetime than any of the character instances. For example, a static object, or an automatic object in the `main` function. That way no character is responsible for the destruction. The tricky part is to make sure that all character instances are destroyed before the game is.
2. Use a reference counting smart pointer such as `std::shared_ptr`. This way the game is destroyed when the last character is.

Comment: I see.  So essentially, due to the fact that there are many characters under one shared game (as you said), the individual characters can safely be destroyed without posing a memory leak, and the main game instance will be deleted when it falls out of scope?

Comment: `and the main game instance will be deleted when it falls out of scope?` If it has automatic storage, then yes. You cannot leak automatic variables. That's why they're called automatic.

Comment: Another option is to have the Game own the Characters, so you have a collection of unique_ptr's to Characters and  Characters can have a  const ref or pointer to the Game. Then when the Game is destroyed all Characters will also be destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you initialize the Game object dynamically, it will not be destroyed until you explicitly do so. So yes, at one point of time, you will need to destroy the Game object if you used pointers and dynamic allocation.

You can test this in the following manner:

```
#include <iostream>
class Game {
public:
    Game() 
    {
        std::cout << "Game Object Initialized\n";
    }
    ~Game()
    {
        std::cout << "Game object destroyed\n";
    }
};
class Character {
    Game *g;
public:
    Character(Game *game, unsigned int x, unsigned int y) {
        g = game;
        std::cout << "Character Object Initialized\n";
    }
    ~Character()
    {
        std::cout << "Character Object Destroyed\n";
    }
};

void main()
{
    Game *gameObj = new Game();
    Character *characterObj = new Character(gameObj, 0, 0);
    delete characterObj;

}
```

> Output:
>
> Game Object Initialized
>
> Character Object Initialized
>
> Character Object Destroyed

In this case `gameObj` is still accesible after `characterObj` is destroyed. You can pass this object to new Characters. Of course, it needs to be destroyed with `delete gameObj;`.

---

If you want the Game object to be destroyed automatically when all characters are deallocated: as others have mentioned, you can use a `shared_ptr` object instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Game {
public:
    Game()
    {
        std::cout << "Game Object Initialized\n";
    }
    ~Game()
    {
        std::cout << "Game object destroyed\n";
    }
};
class Character {
    std::shared_ptr<Game> g;
public:
    Character(std::shared_ptr<Game> game, unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
    {
        g = game;
        std::cout << "Character Object Initialized\n";
    }
    ~Character()
    {
        std::cout << "Character Object Destroyed\n";
    }
};

void main()
{
    //to instantiate a shared_ptr, pass pointer to game as argument in constructor
    std::shared_ptr<Game> gameObj(new Game()); 
    Character *characterObj_0 = new Character(gameObj, 0, 0);
    Character *characterObj_1 = new Character(gameObj, 0, 0);

    delete characterObj_0;
    delete characterObj_1;

    Character *characterObj_2 = new Character(gameObj, 0, 0);

    delete characterObj_2;
}
```

> Game Object Initialized
>
> Character Object Initialized
>
> Character Object Initialized
>
> Character Object Destroyed
>
> Character Object Destroyed
>
> Character Object Initialized
>
> Character Object Destroyed
>
> Game object destroyed